# Is there a logic gate which directly outputs (A'B)' (complement of, A complement product B)?

Tags: digital-logic

[image]

I know I can do this with two separate NAND gates, but it would be more space consuming. Is there a single standard logic gate (e.g.; 74V1Gxxx - SOT-23 package is preferred) which produces this result?

Or, can I get this result by using two transistors at most?

Comment: You should write \$\overline{\overline{A}B} = A + \overline{B}\$ instead of \$\overline{A}B = A + \overline{B}\$. :)

Comment: Ah, you are right. Fixing it now.

Comment: I think there is no such gate as \$\overline{A}B\$. [List of 74XX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure, you could use a [74AXP1G57](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74AXP1G57.pdf) "Low-power configurable multiple function gate"

[image]

[image]

It comes in a very small 6-pin package.

Comment: '1G57 for the smaller problems, '1G99 for the larger ones (no puns intended).

Comment: That's nice, because a dual NAND package would be at least 8 pins.

Comment: Do I read correctly that there are four ways to hook this up as an OR-NOT (A=0, B=1, A=C, B=C) but no way to use it as an OR, NAND or AND-NOT?

Comment: @JanDvorak It's not really a universal gate, but it does some interesting things- most multiple-input gates are symmetric- and the ST inputs are usually an advantage (especially for applications like roll-your-own SMPS designs).

Answer (score 4):

You could wire up a [SN74LVC2G157](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc2g157.pdf) to do this function.

In general, when you need arbitrary logic, think "multiplexer."

Answer (score 3):

You could wire up an [LM556](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm556.pdf) (dual 555 timer IC), with the input stage [wired normally](http://www.pmonta.com/555-contest/logic/logic.html) and the output stage wired as an inverter.

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question, but that link ("Is the 555 complete in the Boolean sense") is loaded with an insane amount of awesomeness (or maybe the reverse).

Comment: People do amazing things with 555s. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would take up more board space than the accepted answer, but it was fun to think about:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2keh8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>